# Idea shortcut 'Go To Implementation(s)' doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, hook, keyboard-shortcuts

I faced a very strange problem: in someday(I don't really know when) the shortcut
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> stoped working. This shortcut is just `Go To Implementation(s)`. I still can do it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse1</kbd>.

I opened settings, to check how is this shortcut configured - all looks fine for me. So I tried to remove <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and add the same combination again.

In `Enter Keyboard Shortcut` window I have to press key's so the IDEA would be able to set this shortcut. But I cannot record these combination, I still can record <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, but not the right combination.

I looked at idea log file, but there was nothing criminal.

I wonder if some other application catches this combination, but I doesn't know how to find this application.

*PS. I run my Idea on win7*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way you're describing it, I strongly believe that the problem is not related to the IDE itself but probably some other program listening for that same key combo in a global level.

Its common to lose some keybinding after installing new applications or drivers. For example, I've lost some key bindings in my IDE after installing drivers for Intel Integrated Graphics. The driver was "stealing" hotkeys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>< arrow ></kbd> used to rotate the screen.

Double check for newly installed or updated programs/drivers, and make sure that they don't have any shortcut that may be conflicting with your IDE.

Also, you might use [Hotkey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) to verify which program is handling your `Ctrl+Alt+B`.

Comment: Oh, Yeah, You were absolutly right - I found that Ctrl+Alt+B used by an application Psi(just an jabber). I discovered it by `Hotkey Commander`, thanks!

Comment: For me it was http://keybase.io app on Mac OS X that overruled the Alt + Cmd + B shortcut when running. Just quit from it to fix.